# How to ignore values in pandas dataframe instead of dropping it

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, regression, analysis

I created a dataset from concatenating a few datasets.
Some of them have an additional column `co2_rating` . I want to keep this as it has a linear relationship with the target variable and so filled the other dataset's `co2_rating` column with 0.

But this affects the relationship between variables.

How can I ignore a certain value or number of values while data analysis or creation of linear regression model training/testing[image]

Comment: I think you can try taking multiple combinations of the features and find out what features work better in fitting the regression line. You can try the ensemble technique like Random forest and then see the feature_importances_. Also, you can use some extrapolation techniques to extrapolate the data points whereever the value is absent and try building a model.

Answer (score 0):

When building linear models, you'll have to fill in the values with measures of central tendency. That is a disadvantage of these models. If you use a random forest, you can just set it to 0, or even -999 and the model can distinguish.

For data analysis, you could just set it to `np.nan`. Matplotlib will automatically ignore those points when plotting.

Alternatively, just filter out those rows before plotting.

```py
sns.scatterplot(x=dataset[dataset['co2_rating'] != 0]['co2_rating'], y=dataset[dataset['co2_rating'] != 0]['co2_emissions'])
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in another answer, `np.nan` may be a better fill value than zeroes are.  For example, `corr()` will ignore `nan`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Toy data with some missing CO2 ratings.
data1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(rating=[np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                          emit=[8, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
data1
#    rating  emit
# 0     NaN     8
# 1     NaN     8
# 2     1.0     2
# 3     2.0     3
# 4     3.0     4
# 5     4.0     5

# Use zero instead of nan for missing values.
data2 = data1.fillna(0)
data2
#    rating  emit
# 0     0.0     8
# 1     0.0     8
# 2     1.0     2
# 3     2.0     3
# 4     3.0     4
# 5     4.0     5

# corr() ignores nan.
data1.corr()
#         rating  emit
# rating     1.0   1.0
# emit       1.0   1.0

# corr() does not ignore zero.
data2.corr()
#           rating      emit
# rating  1.000000 -0.484123
# emit   -0.484123  1.000000
```